# spring integration SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource polling issue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Messages are not returned on the first poll in SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource and logger says

```
DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

```
@Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "inboundFileChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0/10 * * * * *", 
            maxMessagesPerPoll = "${sftp.max.files.per.poll:1}", taskExecutor = "taskExecutor"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer);
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDownloadedDirectory));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setUseWatchService(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(maxFetchSize);
        source.setLocalFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpInboundFileFilterPattern));
        return source;
    }
```

Using spring boot integration

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.15</version>
```

Enabled watch service along with poller interval of 10 seconds

Log

```
2023-06-28 15:13:50.042 DEBUG 74852 --- [  sftp-th-exec1] o.s.i.s.i.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer    : TraceId[] - 1 files transferred from '/sftp/inbound/'

2023-06-28 15:14:00.003 DEBUG 74852 --- [  sftp-th-exec1] sageSource$LocalFileReadingMessageSource : TraceId[] - Watch event [ENTRY_CREATE] for file [XXXXXXX.XXXX]
```

Messages are not returned on the first poll and they return on the second poll after the watch service raises an event.

DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'

Why the behaviour is different ?

Comment: I think this is the way how `WatchService` works: the `ENTRY_CREATE` event not necessarily is generated immediately when we create a file. That remote file is copied to the local one and only after that we pick it up from the local dir emit the message. But apparently `WatchService` has some delay in between. Nothing what we can do unless you try without `WatchService`.